# Windows 7 Time Keeps Changing by 5 hours

Tags: windows-7, windows, clock, utc

I currently have Windows 7 set to use UTC in the hardware clock using this registry hack:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
“RealTimeIsUniversal”=dword:00000001
```

I am in UTC - 5 timezone.  Every so often (probably every 30-40 minutes), my Windows clock is moved backwards five hours (so if it is 2:00 PM in my timezone, it will set my time to 9:00 AM).  This requires me to go in and manually push the clock forward.

I have internet time synchronization and daylight savings adjustments disabled.

Comment: Are your regional settings correct?

Comment: What does your hardware clock (the one on the BIOS's boot setup page) read?

Comment: Would reversing the registry hack, and using the convention method of controlling the system date / time help?